# Instance not storing in my arrayList

Tags: java

I've created a method `addImage` in class `ImageManager` that creates an instance of `Picture` class and adds it to an `ArrayList`.  When you add in image through the `run` class by using `imageManager.addImage("title,image,"Arizona","a;ldkjsf;kasjdf");`
it works just fine.

But when you add an image from the `Parser` class the images `ArrayList` in the `ImageManager` class loses the images created from the `Parser` class between calling the `addImage` method and the `getImages` method but doesn't lose the instance created through the `MainViewController` class.  Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        ImageManager imageManager = new ImageManager();
        imageManager.addImage("title", "location","description");
        parser.parsePictureData();
        imageManager.getImages();
    }
}

public class Parser {

ImageManager imageManager = new ImageManager();
Document document;

public void parsePictureData() {
    try{
        readXMLFile();
        readImageFromDocument();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readXMLFile() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/"+"test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    document = builder.parse(file);
}

private void readImageFromDocument() {
    NodeList pictureNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("picture");
    for(int i = 0; i<pictureNodes.getLength();i++){
        Node pictureNode = pictureNodes.item(i);
        if(pictureNode.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element pictureElement = (Element) pictureNode;
            String location =pictureElement.getAttribute("location");
            String imagePath = pictureElement.getElementsByTagName("path").item(0).getTextContent();
            String title = pictureElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
            String description = pictureElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();

            imageManager.addImage(title,location,description);
        }
    }
}

}

public class ImageManager {

ArrayList<Pictures> images = new ArrayList<>();

public void addImage(String title,  String location, String description){
    Pictures newImage = new Pictures(title, location, description);
    images.add(newImage);
    System.out.println("1"+images);
}

public ArrayList<Pictures> getImages(){
    System.out.println("2"+images);
    return images;
}

}

public class Pictures{

private String title;
private String location;
private String description;


public Pictures(String title, String location, String description){
    this.title = title;
    this.location = location;
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Comment: An MVCE (minimal verifiable complete example) would be better

Comment: @efekctive FYI you can put [] around mcve to get [mcve] ;)

Comment: Changed it to be more of an MCVE

Answer (score 0):

A JavaFX `Image` can only be used in one scene graph. Try storing `ImageView`s, and creating the `Image` via `Image image = new Image(imageView);`. Multiple `Images` can be created from the same `ImageView`.